# How to access YAML info in another page in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll

I'm just getting started with Jekyll (and Ruby). In a page, I want to reference *another* page, by storing its filename in a YAML var, like so:

```
---
heading: My Page 1
related_page: my_page2.html
---

my page content here.
```

So far so good. Now, the problem I'm facing is that I'd like to get access to my_page2.html's YAML information, for use in *My Page 1*, above. Rather crudely (imagine otherpage actually refers to the related_page & contains a heading YAML var), something like this:

```
The heading of {{ page.related_page }} is {{ otherpage.heading }}
```

I've been looking around other Jekyll plugins for something similar, but can't seem to find anything close.

Any tips on how you'd do this?

Comment: Writing your own plugins for Jekyll is pretty straightforward; I would suggest you to go that way.

Comment: @mudasobwa: If you don't know Ruby, it is not so easy. I have been programming for almost 30 years now, but would still have problems writing a suitable plugin in Ruby. The OP just started with Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll **site.related_posts** is a solution ([see documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/)).

But you can have a look at [Lawrence Woodman related-posts plugin](https://github.com/LawrenceWoodman/related_posts-jekyll_plugin).